# how to make my usb storage or sd card the default instal location

Tags: google-play-store

My techno g9 device shows internal storage 0.99G Usb storage 12 G and Sd Card 27G. All installed apps go to the .99G which is full. So i cant dowload any new apps. Please how can i change the instal folder to the 12G usb storage or the 27G Sd card.

Answer (score 0):

**Settings**

**Storage**

Preferred installed location. Select **SD card**

---

In Storage you can also set the **SD card** to **Primary Storage**.

---

Try the steps an see if your device has the function.